# Using Oracle DB. Issue with columns name starting with $ symbol

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jasper-reports

I have to make a report using *Oracle 11g* database.

So it has column names starts with *`$`* symbol, like this: ***T$QOOR***.

Then I designed the report and try to set field, but it given error

> com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.errorhandler.ProblemItem@18e52c3
>   Syntax error on token "$F", AssignmentOperator expected after this
>   token net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignExpression@d2bc90

How can I omit this error?

Comment: Try to use alias in query. For example `SELECT T$QOOR AS qoor ...`

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle's database object naming rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) forbid an object, for instance a table, from beginning with a dollar sign. It must have been created as a quoted identifier. So, if you want to reference this column you *have* to quote it.

```
select "$COL"...
```

Oracle allows cased object names within double quotes so the name must be *completely* identical.

If you want your life to be easy do not have cased column/table/object names within the database. It's not worth the hassle. Having said that, your referenced column, `T$QOOR`, does *not* begin with a dollar...